# My nested for loop is outputting duplicates

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

The aim of this function is to **pass in**: `[{lang: 'English', proficiency: 'Elementary Proficiency'}, {lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency'}]`.

And have the function **print out**: `[{level: 1, lang: 'English', proficiency: 'Elementary Proficiency'}, { level:3, lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency'}]`.

**However, I'm getting**: `[{level:3, lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency}, {level:3, lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency}]`. ANY IDEAS? Thank you.

```
lngSort(exObj) {
      let userprof = []
      let lng = []

      const proficiencies = [
        { level: 1, name: 'Elementary Proficiency' },
        { level: 2, name: 'Limited Working Proficiency' },
        { level: 3, name: 'Full Professional Proficiency' },
        { level: 4, name: 'Native Bilingual Proficiency' }
      ]

      for(let v in exObj) {
        userprof.push(exObj[v].proficiency);
        lng.push(exObj[v].lang);
      }

      let findmax = (proficiencies, userprof) => {
          const arr = [];
          const ob = {};

          let found = false;
          for (const prof of proficiencies) {
            for (const user of userprof) {
              if (found) found = false
              for (const l of lng) {
                if (prof.name === user) {
                  ob.level = qual.level
                  ob.proficiency = qual.name
                  ob.lang = l
                  arr.push(ob);
                  found = true
                  break
                }
              }
            }
          }
          console.log("QUAL: " + JSON.stringify(arr))
      }
      findmax(proficiencies, userqual);
    }
```

Comment: Just an input and output is not enough. Please provide an input and output **as well as explaining what you want your code to do in a higher-level sense**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like using `map` is simpler solution for this question.

```js
const proficiencies = [
  { level: 1, name: 'Elementary Proficiency' },
  { level: 2, name: 'Limited Working Proficiency' },
  { level: 3, name: 'Full Professional Proficiency' },
  { level: 4, name: 'Native Bilingual Proficiency' }
];

const items = [
  { lang: 'English', proficiency: 'Elementary Proficiency' },
  { lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency' }
];


const res = items.map((item) => {
  const proficiency = proficiencies.find(i => i.name === item.proficiency);
  if (proficiency) {
    item.level = proficiency.level;
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only breaking the deepest level of `for`. You need to break the others too. Currently, the next loop doesn't break, starts over, and the first instruction in this loop is `if (found) found = false`, which resets your boolean, so the job is done again.

```
for (const prof of proficiencies) {
    for (const user of userprof) {
        if (found) found = false
        for (const l of lng) {
            if (prof.name === user) {
                ob.level = qual.level
                ob.proficiency = qual.name
                ob.lang = l
                arr.push(ob);
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }
    if (found) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure your `proficiencies` array as an object this becomes very simple with a single `map()`.

```js
const input = [{lang: 'English', proficiency: 'Elementary Proficiency'}, {lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency'}];

const proficiencies = {
        'Elementary Proficiency': 1,
        'Limited Working Proficiency': 2,
        'Full Professional Proficiency': 3, 
        'Native Bilingual Proficiency': 4
      }

const out = input.map(o => ({level: proficiencies[o.proficiency],...o}));

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slightly different approach to your problem which you might find easier to implement. Rather than using multiple loops, you can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (which behaves much like an object, it keeps key-value pairs that can later be accessed using `.get(key)`). The map can be built from the `proficiency` array using the `Map` constructor. The map constructor takes an array of `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...]` pairs which you can build using the [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on your array. Once you have built the map it will have the following structure:

```
"Elementary Proficiency" => 1
"Limited Working Proficiency" => 2
"Full Professional Proficiency" => 3
"Native Bilingual Proficiency" => 4
```

Where the numbers are the values which can be obtained from the map by using `.get(proficiencyName)`. Once you have this structure, all you need to do is transform all the objects in your original array to have a `level` property. To do this, I have used `.map()` again, which will build a new object using the properties of each object currently present in your array (this is done using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...`), and will add an additional `level` property which represents the level that is obtained by looking up the object's proficiency in the Map we made above:

```js
const arr = [{lang: 'English', proficiency: 'Elementary Proficiency'}, {lang: 'Spanish', proficiency: 'Full Professional Proficiency'}];
const proficiencies = [ { level: 1, name: 'Elementary Proficiency' }, { level: 2, name: 'Limited Working Proficiency' }, { level: 3, name: 'Full Professional Proficiency' }, { level: 4, name: 'Native Bilingual Proficiency' } ];

const levelLookUp = new Map(proficiencies.map(o => [o.name, o.level]));
const result = arr.map(obj => ({level: levelLookUp.get(obj.proficiency), ...obj}));

console.log(result);
```

Building a Map first will be more performant as your array input sizes grow large, as it will only require you to loop over your `proficiencies` array and your input array once independently, rather than using nested loops which can have performance implications.